# Select top 2 rows different from each other

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
 |      date    |  sum  |
 |--------------|-------|
 | 2015-02-19   | 10000 |
 | 2015-02-19   | 10000 |
 | 2015-02-20   | 15000 |
 | 2015-02-20   | 15000 |
 | 2015-02-21   | 18000 |
 | 2015-02-21   | 18000 |
```

I want to select top 2 rows from the table, but only different ones, meaning my result should return `2015-02-20` and `2015-02-21`.

```
SELECT TOP 2 distinct date 
FROM stock
```

Using this gives me an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What order are you using?

Comment: i'm using "ORDER BY date DESC"

Comment: Do you care about `sum` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
select top 2 * from
(
    select distinct date FROM stock
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
SELECT TOP 2 date 
FROM stock
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Distinct and Top should switch places in your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 date FROM stock ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   select distinct top 2 date  from stock
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 2 date 
FROM stock
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Sample result:

```
DATE
2015-02-21
2015-02-20
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b3b7/9).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  WITH cte AS
 ( SELECT distinct date ,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date
                          ORDER BY date DESC
                         )
         AS rn
   FROM stock
 )
 SELECT date
 FROM cte
 WHERE rn <= 3
 ORDER BY rn ;
```

Comment: You ignored the part about distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 date FROM stock group by date
```

Comment: @Anik Islam Abhi  No difference, when i was posting the answer SMA i did not see the post.